# unexpected T_IF error in PHP

Tags: php

I have a small problem with this code and i cannot understand why is returning `unexpected T_IF`

code:

```
$get_gender = array($getGender->getMaleGender());
$gender =  

if ($gender->getGender()) { 
    echo "Male"; 
} else { 
    echo "Female"; 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Solution:

```
$get_gender = array($getGender->getMaleGender()); 
                if ($getGender->getIsMaleGender()) { 
                    $result = "Male"; 
                } else { 
                    $result = "Female";
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot inline an `if`-construction like that.

Depending on how your functions look, try the following:

```
if ($getGender->getMaleGender()) { 
    $gender = "Male"; 
} else { 
    $gender = "Female";
}
```

or the shorthand syntax:

```
$gender = $getGender->getMaleGender() ? 'Male' : 'Female';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the ternary operator. You can't define a variable with an if statement.

```
$gender = $gender->getGender() ? 'Male' : 'Female';
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning anything on the 2nd line

```
$gender = // what goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start with removing the following line

```
  $gender =
```

it is not correct.